# Overriding the default font size in a Slidy presentation

Tags: css, xhtml, slidy

I'm trying to create a presentation using [Slidy](http://www.w3.org/Talks/Tools/Slidy2/), and I want to increase the default font-size.

Slidy presentations have default styling set in [this CSS file](http://www.w3.org/Talks/Tools/Slidy2/styles/slidy.css), which includes the line `font-size: 14pt;` in the `body` element.

Here's a minimalist Slidy presentation where I override this font size in a style block in the page head:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> 
<head> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection, print" 
   href="http://www.w3.org/Talks/Tools/Slidy2/styles/slidy.css" /> 
  <script src="http://www.w3.org/Talks/Tools/Slidy2/scripts/slidy.js" 
   charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <style type="text/css"> 
    body {
      font-size: 128pt;
    }
  </style> 
</head>
<body>
  <div class="slide">
    <p>Some text that ought to be bigger.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In Internet Explorer, the text is large, as I expected. Firefox and Chrome display small text however.  They definitely notice the style block in the page (I can change `font-family`, or other CSS properties here); they just doesn't seem to want to change the font size.

How should I specify that I want a large default font size?

Answer (score 3):

@f.n174's answer is probably the correct way to fix things for a general xhtml page.  Slidy seems to be doing something odd with CSS evaluation, so we need to expoit a trick to change the default font size for all types.

The contents of a slide are contained in an item of class `slide`, so we can change the font-size for all text tags at once using:

```
.slide {
  font-size: 128pt;
}
```

This works in Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

add `style="font-size:128px"` in your body element as an attribute if this not worked add  the code in your `<p>` element

Comment: Adding the attribute to the body element doesn't change the size. (This is weird, right? Inline styles really ought to override anything else.)  Setting the font-size for `<p>` does work (whether I set it as an attribute or in a `<style>` block, though I'm a little reluctant to do this since it means I also have to change it for all the other text types (`<ul>`/`<ol>`, etc.).

Comment: you can write all element names at the begin of the css file and apply font size to them. li,ul,ol,p,etc{font-size:128px}